# Android TableLayout dynamic or fixed size

Tags: android, size, android-tablelayout

I am an Android newbie and I am wondering what to do regarding a big table I want to display.

Currently I am testing a **TableLayout** with **100 TableRows**. The final table will have much more rows, in the order of the **thousands**.
Since TableLayout is a **View**, I wonder what is the correct, or recommended, approach in this case. To use a View (TableLayout) containing all the data I have, or dynamically add/delete  rows in the viewable window, as the user scrolls up and down.

What are the pros and cons of the different approaches? Examples?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clearest disadvantage to having them all on screen at the same time is that the OS essentially has to have all of your thousands of View objects in memory at the same time - **VERY** expensive, memory-wise.

On the other hand, creation and destruction of views as you scroll is processor intensive and slows down the UI considerably.

The primary alternative (and the one that android uses in its `ListView` control (Which is probably what you should use instead, by the way), is to only create enough views to fill the screen (plus a little padding on either side), and as one goes off the top, re-use it at the bottom, changing its properties rather than creating a whole new view.

The above is complicated logic, though, and why reinvent the wheel?  The [List View control](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) with a [custom adapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) should be more than capable of rendering the data like you're attempting to do, and the hard work has already been done.

Comment: I Agree. I don't want to reinvent the wheel. Do you know where can I see some code example of this technique?

Comment: This one is relatively thorough... Should get Hulu pointed In the right direction. http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/

Comment: Many thanks. One last detail: Seeing the XMLs in the example you sent I wonder if a ListView element can have any number of son elements? If I put there 10 TextViews, can I iterate through them and make them VISIBLE/INVISIBLE?

Comment: @ilomambo an Item in a listView can have as many children as you want to deal with - setting them visible/invisible would be the job of the adapter in the `getView()` method